# How to access a list passed a parameter to a function inside the function?

Tags: python, python-3.4

How to access the list sent as a parameter to function inside the function?

```
def my_fun(mylist):
    mylist[0]=a
    mylist[1]=b
    mylist[2]=c
    mylist[3]=d
    e=a+b
    f=c+d
    return (e,f))
val = [1,2,3,4]
my_fun(val)
```

> NameError: name 'a' is not defined

Comment: `a=mylist[0]` assign this way.

Comment: Your assignments are not set the right way. You want to assign the value of a list to a variable, therefore you need to have `a` on the left side and the `myList` on the right side of the assignment operator. As already mentioned in the previous comment, you want => `a = myList[0]`

Answer (score 0):

You dont want to assign your list index to a variable (mylist[0] = a) but the other way around (a = mylist[0]), so that you can store the values when a list is passed as an argument.

```
def my_fun(mylist):
    a = mylist[0]
    b = mylist[1]
    c = mylist[2]
    d = mylist[3]
    e=a+b
    f=c+d
    return (e,f)


def main():
    val = [1,2,3,4]
    x = my_fun(val)
    print(x)
main()
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking is `globals()` scope dictionary. Python has 2 functions `locals()` that return local variable dictionary inside the scope, and `globals()` that return global variables outside the scope. Both functions return a `dict` which change during execution. So you can change, check for change or even change them artificially during your code.

Let's say you have this type of code:

```
a = 4;
b = 3;
c = 5;
d = 2;  

# version 1
def my_fun(mylist):

    global a,b,c,d; # mentioning them as global variables

    mylist[0]=a
    mylist[1]=b
    mylist[2]=c
    mylist[3]=d
    e=a+b
    f=c+d
    return (e,f)
```

By declaring `global a,b,c,d` you are placing them temporarily in global namespace. This way you can access the global variables from inside the function.

```
# or version 2  
def my_fun2(mylist):
    mylist[0]=globals()['a']
    mylist[1]=globals()['b']
    mylist[2]=globals()['c']
    mylist[3]=globals()['d']
    e=globals()['a']+globals()['b']
    f=globals()['c']+globals()['d']
    return (e,f)
```

By calling `globals()` and calling the variable name **`['a']`** you are accessing directly global namespace and as any dictionary you can change it by your will. But be carefull, changing variables starting with and ending `__` (underscores) [ like `__name__` can mess up your code, sometimes even interpreter. So keep track what you are changing and what you are changing it to.

```
#version 3  
def my_fun3(mylist):
    mylist[0]=globals()['a']
    mylist[1]=globals()['b']
    mylist[2]=globals()['c']
    mylist[3]=globals()['d']
    # changing of the global variables.
    globals()['a'] = mylist[0]+mylist[1];
    globals()['b'] = mylist[2]+mylist[3];
```

Be careful with this information, and test them in interpreter(IDE) first before committing to your code.

To get more information about function ( name, argument names, constants and etc ), you can do next:

```
>>def a():return 0
>>a.__code__ #grabs code object  
>>a.__code__.co_name # gets the name of the function you can search
```

And more information on what you can call from `__code__` object is `dir(f_name.__code__)` where **f_name** is `a` in this case.